# Covariance equality for independent Gaussians

Tags: inequality, normal-distribution, covariance

$X = Y + Z$ are independent Gaussians with zero means. I'm told that:$$Cov(Y,X) = \sigma_{Y}^2$$

Could someone show me the intermediate steps to get there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because $$\text{Cov}(Y,X)=\text{Cov}(Y,Y+Z)=\text{Cov}(Y,Y)+\text{Cov}(Y,Z)=\text{Var}(Y)$$
Since $\text{Cov}(Y,Z)=0$ because of their independence.

Remember that 
$$\mathbb{E}\left[ \sum X_i\right]=\sum \mathbb{E}[X_i]=\sum \mu_i$$
Then $$\begin{align} \text{Cov}\left (\sum X_i, \sum Y_i\right) &= \mathbb{E}\left [\left(\sum X_i-\sum \mu_i\right)\left(\sum Y_i-\sum \nu_i\right)\right] \\
&= \mathbb{E}\left [\sum \left(X_i- \mu_i\right)\sum\left( Y_i- \nu_i\right)\right]\\ &=\mathbb{E}\left [\sum \sum \left(X_i- \mu_i\right)\left( Y_i- \nu_i\right)\right]\\ &=\sum \sum \mathbb{E}\left [\left(X_i- \mu_i\right)\left( Y_i- \nu_i\right)\right]\end{align}$$

Comment: Why does $Cov(Y,Y+Z)=Cov(Y,Y)+Cov(Y,Z)$? Sorry not seeing it.

Comment: @Jake do you know the formula for covariance?

Comment: $Cov(X,Y)=E[XY]-E[X]E[Y]$

Comment: Oh ok I figured it out just took me more steps than I expected

Comment: @Jake I added a derivation for more general use